# Is there a way to separate reducer actions in a different file from createSclice in redux?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have this redux slice setup in `store/slices/sourcesSlice.ts`

```
import { addInitialSources} from "store/slices/sourcesActions.ts";
export const sourcesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "sourcesSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addSource: (state, action: PayloadAction<SourceInterface>) => {
      state.sources.push(action.payload);
    },
    changeName: (state) => {
      state.naming = "Bob Marley";
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(addInitialSources.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.sources = payload;
      }) 
  },
});
export const { addSource, changeName } = sourcesSlice.actions;
```

Note how I have a number of actions in `store/slices/sourcesSlice.ts` and a number of actions in `store/slices/sourcesActions.ts`

All `addSource`, `changeName`, `addInitialSources` are related actions. **Shouldn't they all be accessible from one endpoint? So when I import any of those, I think it's cleaner, easier to remember if I can do this

```
import { addInitialSources, addSource, changeName} from "store/slices/sourcesActions.ts";
```

Rather than this

```
import { addInitialSources} from "store/slices/sourcesActions.ts";
import { addSource, changeName} from "store/slices/sourcesSlice.ts";
```

Is such a thing possible? To leave `export const sourcesSlice = createSlice...` in `sourcesSlice.ts` but to call all the actions from `sourcesActions.ts`

**AND IS IT RECOMMENDED**